# Find week number of Specific Month and Year

Tags: php

I am Using Bellow Script. but it give me Result but not According To My Requirement.

This is the Week number i need. [Week Calendar](http://week-number.net/calendar-with-week-numbers-2016.html)

```
$month = "10";
$year = "2016";
$beg = (int) date('W', strtotime("first monday of $year-$month"));
$end = (int) date('W', strtotime("last  monday of $year-$month"));   
print(join(', ', range($beg, $end)));
```

above code Gives Result. 40, 41, 42, 43, 44

Comment: What did you expect? And may use `first/last day of`.

Comment: there is a Link Week Calendar. which have october - 39,40,41,42,43,44

Comment: then `day of` should work

Comment: No!! not working for me. can you please give Answer this Question.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP >= 5.3 do

```
$month = "10";
$year = "2016";
$beg = (int) date('W', strtotime("first day of $year-$month"));
$end = (int) date('W', strtotime("last day of $year-$month"));   
print(join(', ', range($beg, $end)));
```

Comment: it gives result - 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1